Showing system of equations as Euler-Lagrange for functional
If $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a bounded domain.$\frac{2d}{d-2}>p>2$, then  $$
\Delta u + |u|^{p-2}u=0 \textrm{ in } \Omega
$$
$$
u=0 \textrm{ on } \partial \Omega
$$
are the Euler-Lagrange equations in $H_{0}^{1, 2}(\Omega)$ for the functional
$$
F(u)= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} |Du|^2 -\frac{1}{p} \int_{\Omega}{|u|^{p}}
$$
Above is question. 
I need to show that for $u$ satisfying the system of equations and for any $w \in H_{0}^{1, 2}(\Omega)$, $F(u) \leq F(w)$, but I get stuck after two line simplification. I tried to do
$$0 = \int_{\Omega}(\Delta u+|u|^{p-2}u )( u-w) dx$$
if focused on just first one
$$
 \int_{\Omega} \Delta u (u - w) \, dx
$$
$$
= - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 \, dx + \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla w \, dx
$$
$$
\leq - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 \, dx + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} \left( |\nabla u|^2 + |\nabla w|^2 \right) \, dx
$$
$$
= - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 \, dx + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} |\nabla w|^2 \, dx.
$$
but no idea to proceed further for second expression $\int_{\Omega} |u|^{p-2}u(u-w) dx$

I do not see any differential operators. Is this intended? Your first equation immediately yields $u = 0$.

sorry i will post full question. I did part question post and it might have been a problem

Have you tried computing the second variation of the functional? It looks like it won’t be hard to show it is positive definite

use convexity of $u \mapsto |u|^p$. Also the sign of $\int|u|^p$ should be plus iinstead of minus in the definition of $F$.

@daw so I can use the convexity that includes derivative since it's only not diferentiable at 0 and its fine.

@whpowell96, I will try that also..

Since $p>2$ the nonlinear term is twice differentiable at $0$
